# XmlDocument throwing "An error occurred while parsing EntityName"

Tags: c#, xml, string, xmldocument

I have a function where I am passing a string as params called filterXML which contains '&' in one of the properties.

I know that XML will not recognize it and it will throw me an err. Here is my code:

```
 public XmlDocument TestXMLDoc(string filterXml)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode root = doc.CreateElement("ResponseItems");

    // put that root into our document (which is an empty placeholder now)
    doc.AppendChild(root);

    try
    {
        XmlDocument docFilter = new XmlDocument();
        docFilter.PreserveWhitespace = true;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterXml) == false)
            docFilter.LoadXml(filterXml); //ERROR THROWN HERE!!!
```

What should I change in my code to edit or parse filterXml? My filterXml looks like this:

```
<Testing>
<Test>CITY & COUNTY</Test>
</Testing>
```

I am changing my string value from & to &. Here is my code for that:

```
string editXml = filterXml;
    if (editXml.Contains("&"))
    {
        editXml.Replace('&', '&amp;');
    }
```

But its giving me an err on inside the if statement : Too many literals.

Comment: It's erroring out because of the ampersand (&)

Comment: This is late in the game, but in case anyone else stumbles across it - the "Too many literals" error is caused by the fact that Gunda used single quotes around his "&amp;". Single quotes indicate chars, which are only allowed to be a single character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file shown above is not well-formed XML because the ampersand is not escaped.

You can try with:

```
<Testing>
  <Test>CITY &amp; COUNTY</Test>
</Testing>
```

or:

```
<Testing>
  <Test><![CDATA[CITY & COUNTY]]></Test>
</Testing>
```

Comment: I am doing something like this: string editXml = filterXml;
        if (editXml.Contains("&"))
        {
            editXml.Replace('&', '&amp;');
        }

Comment: Option 2 is a bit overkill though and overall, not very useful in this case.

Comment: I would advise caution. This will work if you are sure that all ampersands are "not well-formed". If your input XML document is well-formed and contains entity or character references, doing so might break them (for example, a well-formed &amp; will be changed to &amp;amp;). If you have control over this, it might be easier to ensure well-formedness earlier in the data flow (when the content of filterXml is generated).

Answer (score 2):

About the second question: there are two signatures for String.Replace. One that takes characters, the other that takes strings. Using single quotes attempts to build character literals - but "&amp;", for C#, is really a string (it has five characters).

Does it work with double quotes?

```
editXml.Replace("&", "&amp;");
```

If you would like to be a bit more conservative, you could also write code to ensure that the &s you are replacing are not followed by one of

```
amp; quot; apos; gt; lt; or #
```

(but this would still not be a perfect filtering)

Answer (score 1):

To specify an ampersand in XML you should use `&amp;` since the ampersand sign ('&') has a special meaning in XML.